# Hidden Form Field Not Storing Variable

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have the following form:

**form**

```
<?php
echo '<td><form action="episodesdelete.php" method="POST">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="epid" value="'.$row['epid'].'">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Delete"></form></td>';
?>
```

Which is part of a function to display MySQL data in an HTML table.

For some reason, when i look at the hidden field with FireBug, it is empty. Could you please advise due to what that can be?

Comment: Can you show what is in the $row variable? It is possible the input is empty because your row is empty (for whatever reason).

Comment: It has been a mistake of mine regardless of this-forgot to define epid in DB:) - But thanks for the help anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is $row assigned its value?

A very common mistake is to not check for failed queries.  Make sure to check every query execution for errors, like so:

```
$result = mysql_query($query_text) or die("Error running query " . mysql_error());
```

If that line gets passed (the query succeeds), make sure that $row is getting assigned a valid value (by a function like `mysql_fetch_array` perhaps?).

And, if that checks out, run the query yourself from the command line to verify that the results are what you expect (and that the query is not actually returning an empty string).

Comment: Like I said above- 
It has been a mistake of mine regardless of this-forgot to define epid in DB:) But thanks for the help!